# How to get input provided in a textarea tag using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Have a `textarea` tag in form, to take input text and return the value of said text.

```
 <textarea id="code" name="code"></textarea>
```

Using javascript to get the value, but it returns nothing. Used `typeof` to check if it's `undefined`, but `typeof text` gives `'string'`. Is this correct way to use `.value`? How to improve this?

JavaScript:

```
var text = document.getElementById('code').value;

document.getElementById('submit-button').onclick = function() {
    alert(text);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the event and get the value just when the user clicks the button.

*Embrace the function `addEventListener`*

```js
document.getElementById('submit-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var text = document.getElementById('code').value;
    console.log(text);
});
```

```html
<textarea id="code" name="code"></textarea>
<button type="button" id="submit-button">click me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the value immediately when the page loads, before the user has had a chance to type anything.  You want to get the value when the user clicks the button:

```js
document.getElementById('submit-button').onclick = function() {
    var text = document.getElementById('code').value;
    alert(text);
};
```

```html
<textarea id="code" name="code"></textarea>
<button type="button" id="submit-button">click me</button>
```

Comment: I was just informed that I have a scope issue. I was defining a variable that I thought I could put in a function. However I am told that because this is a callback the rules are a bit different.

Answer (score 0):

Stick the `var text` line inside the click event; it's getting defined when the script runs originally, so it is just an empty string.

```
document.getElementById('submit-button').onclick = function() {
    var text = document.getElementById('code').value;
    alert(text);
};
```

Comment: Thanks! this did it.